# Understanding callbacks in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

```
function firstFunction(_callback){
    // do some asynchronous work
    // and when the asynchronous stuff is complete
    _callback();    
}

function secondFunction(){
    // call first function and pass in a callback function which
    // first function runs when it has completed
    firstFunction(function() {
        console.log('huzzah, I\'m done!');
    });    
}
```

This is an example from this site, I would like help understanding it.

If I have a function that sums 2 number and the other returns it. So:

```
   var z = 0;
    function firstf (x, y, callback){
    z = x + y;
        callback();
    }
function  secondf () {
    console.log(z);
}
```

I dont get how this works? How do I make it so that `secondf` waits until `firstf` is done **using callbacks?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By re-ordering your code:

*edit* Made code async for demo purposes

```js
var z = 0;

function firstf(x, y, callback) {
  console.log("Inside firstf");
  z = x + y;
  console.log("Will call callback in 1 second");
  // Lets make this function async.
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Calling callback");
    callback();
  }, 1000);
}

function secondf() {
  console.log("Inside secondf");
  console.log(z);
  console.log("Leaving secondf");
}


firstf(1, 2, secondf);
```

Comment: What if the inside is async? I mean what if firstf was async?

Comment: made the code async -- no change, other than a one second delay.

Comment: Is it safe to always delay something 1000ms? If I have an async code running, but I want something else to run after it finishes, is set timeout 1000 a good bet?

Comment: No.. not at all. If you have async code running, don't make the callback until the async code has finished.  Without knowing what the async function is, its hard to say *how* to tell when it's finished.  If it provides a callback, great -- use it.  Otherwise, you'll have to be far more specific.   Added note, you might want to look into Promises -- it can help write far cleaner code.

Comment: I've tried a callback in my application here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406029/js-waiting-for-one-function-to-finish-before-second-with-async-in-first  but even with the callback, the callback executes before the db tasks are finished. How to correct this with the callback?

Comment: You should remove the global `z` variable and instead pass it as a parameter to the callback

Answer (score 0):

After define 2 function, you call:

```
firstf(2,3,secondf);
```

Follow :  `z=2+3`  then `call` function `callback`. And now, function `callback` ~ `secondf` :

```
z=2+3 ;
secondf();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the second block to wait until the first block is done. Then using callback makes no sense.
Because the main concept of callback is to provide an asynchronous platform.

A callback is a function call at the completion of a given task, hence prevents any blocking which may might occur if the first block takes long time to load data.

So, if you want both the blocks to work asynchronously the use callback, and to achieve what you are asking simply call the second function after the task of block one is done.

For better understanding go through this link,
https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "promise" concept to ensure that the `secondf` waits until `firstf` is done:

```
function firstf(x,y){
    return new Promise(
       function (resolve, reject) {
          resolve(x+y);
       });
}

function secondf(){
   firstf(x,y).then ( function (result){
      console.log(result);
   });
}
```