# JS waiting for one function to finish before second, with async in first?

Tags: javascript

```
var membersStatArray = [];

function runFirst (callback) {
    db.group.findOne({_id: id}).then((groupFound) => {
        var membersArray = groupFound.members;
        membersArray.forEach(function (member) {
            db.doneTodo.find({'victor._id': member._id}).then((arrayOfUserVictories) =>{
                membersStatArray.push({email: member.email, victories: arrayOfUserVictories.length});
            })
        });
        callback();
    });

}

function runSecond() {
    console.log(membersStatArray);
    res.status(305).send();
}

runFirst(runSecond);
```

The functions in the `runFirst` are async so I called the console to print out the `membersStatArray` in the secondFunc, but it still prints `[]`, how can I correct this with this **callback** function?

Comment: This looks essentially the same as your previous question. Please respond to that question first.

Comment: @4castle, I'm trying to do this using callbacks, the methods they've shown is different

Comment: Your callback is in the wrong place .. it fires off as soon as your database access fires off. It doesn't wait for the database respose to be processed.  I was typing up a longer answer when the question got closed, but in short it needs to go after your ` membersArray.forEach` loop

Comment: You will find that your other question is the same as this one. Just put `runSecond` where the console log is in the other question.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, it still shows an empty []. I've fixed the code, and now it shows it after the loop. Please have a look!

Comment: @4castle, that doesnt change anything

Comment: Have you tried using the code in my answer yet? Replace `membersArray.forEach` with my code, and execute the callback in the `then` after the `Promise.all`

Comment: @4castle, I could try it, but I dont understand anything from it. I'm trying to use a method I could understand